# Text goes outside the div while resizing the website

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am converting an existing website, so that it's responsive. I am working on

```
http://dubaiexporters.com/member_benefits.aspx
```

When I'm resizing the browser, the text goes outside of the div.

[image]

What can i do, so that text does not go outside div?

Code:

```
<div class="roundedcornr_box">
        <div class="roundedcornr_top">
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="roundedcornr_content">
            <div class="postpage">
                <div class="customh1">
                    <h1 class="posthead">
                        Memberships & Benefits</h1>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="mainAdlistAds">
                    <div class="silverAds">
                         <div class="adContent" style="position:absolute;">
                            <ul><li><a href="pdf/Dubai_Exporters_Member_Certficate.pdf" target="_blank">DubaiExporters Membership Certificate </a></li> 
                                <li>Log in to access and edit the Company profile. </li>
                                <li>Access to the latest inquiries received from agents, importers, distributors all
                                    over the world.</li>
                                <li>Company’s Logo , profile & the website link in the Supplier’s section.</li>
                                <li>Advertisement of the Company shall be included in the Listing.</li>
                                <li>Weekly Newsletter updates from Dubai Exporters containing latest news about the
                                    world economy, export scenarios, upcoming projects, trade events, market reviews
                                    and the link to the Member’s Profile on Dubai Exporters, shall be mailed to our
                                    entire database of over 150000 Importers from Africa, CIS,Eastern Europe, latin
                                    America, Asia.&nbsp;<a class="lightbox" href="images/newslettertemplate.jpg">View sample</a></li>
                                <li>A CD of Dubai Exporters shall be distributed to all the trade visitors and importers
                                    visiting Int’l trade exhibitions where Dubai Exporters participates, thereby making
                                    your company’s information reach the right target audience. </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div style="float: right; padding:15px 60px 0px 0px;">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btSilver" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/mem_btn.png"
                                     /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            </div>

        <div class="roundedcornr_bottom">
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am new to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because this block has an image as a gray background http://dubaiexporters.com/images/SILVER-member.jpg (which has its own dimensions) and a height is set on this block - 
.silverAds {
height:372px
}

Remove height or turn it into min-height and then do smth about gray picture - either stretch it vertically in an editor or add background-color with a border to .silverAds

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text not to be shown over the border of the element, you have to set overflow.

```
.element { overflow: scroll;}
```

or

```
.element { overflow: hidden;}
```

Edit: 
As the `position: absolute` is taking the content out of the element.
You should set the parent container to `position: relative` & `height: auto;`

Comment: i tried putting overflow but still it goes outside div